# Is not stopping for a damaged car wing mirror counted as a hit-and-run?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, england-and-wales, motor-vehicle

It is a fairly common occurance for many motorists to have either a car wing mirror damaged or knocked off, especially on tight and difficult to navigate roads in the UK where there is little room to maneuver:
[image: A picture of a narrow country road]

Assuming a car mirror has been knocked off, and the driver has not stopped, does this constitute a road collision or an example of failing to stop, even if no-one has been injured?

Comment: "Fairly common"? [citation needed]. I don't know anyone who has had this happen.

Comment: @JonCuster This has happened to me in fact, as well as numerous family, colleagues, and friends.

Answer (score 1):

### Depends on what you damaged

If you are the driver and the accident resulted in personal injury to someone other than you or damage to another vehicle, property or an animal then you must stop and provide your details with the other parties to the accident. You don't have to stop if only you or your property was damaged.

It's possible that you damaged the hedge and should have left a note but it seems unlikely that you would be prosecuted.

Of course, if you leave bits of your wing mirror at the scene, that's littering.