# Must all accidents be reported to your insurance company in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, insurance, motor-vehicle, car-insurance

**Disclaimer** - This is a follow on question from [the previous one I asked](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/88817/is-not-stopping-for-a-damaged-car-wing-mirror-counted-as-a-hit-and-run) on whether it is a crime to fail to stop.

Let's say I have some sort of minor damage to my car, such as a scratch/dent from another passing car or a my wing mirror being damaged. As the cost of repairing the car is either negligable (as in the case of a scratch) or low enough that all it would do is raise the cost of my insurance premium, would I need to still notify my car insurance company of the accident, according to law?

Comment: Does the insurance policy actually require you to report every incident?

Answer (score -1):

### What does your insurance contract say?

If the contract says you have to report it, and you don't then you have breached your policy and your insurer may be able to avoid liability for future claims due to that breach.

Notwithstanding, when renewing your insurance you are required to [disclose](https://lawhandbook.sa.gov.au/ch25s01s02s03.php) any matter that may increase the risk to the insurer. The fact that you are a driver who runs into things is probably such a factor.

Comment: If they may avoid liability for future claims they you should avoid liability for paying them.  Also, if you have a law that backs your second paragraph then please cite it.  I have been renewing my policy every 6 months for decades now and have never disclosed anything I didn't submit a claim for.

Comment: @MichaelHall done

Comment: The question is tagged England-and-Wales.  The duty of utmost good faith for insurance contracts has been considerably weakened in E&W.  If the insurance company doesn't ask about it, you don't have to tell them.  (Having said that, all _my_ insurance policies have asked about things "whether a claim has been made or not".)

Comment: One could argue you don’t have to report “any matter”, only “material facts”.  Minor scratches, that aren’t claimed, (may not even be repaired) and if they were would fall within the deductible, do not increase risk to the insurer, and are therefore irrelevant.

Comment: @MichaelHall and a counter point is the fact that you allow your car to get “minor scratches” (for whatever reason) is an indication that you don’t take as much care as other car owners and are therefore higher risk.

Comment: Not necessarily.  I have known people who don't care very much about cosmetic dings from car doors or shopping carts, or scratches from branches on narrow jeep roads because they drive older trucks, but they are very safe drivers, and carry insurance with high deductibles only to cover major damage from a severe collision.  Which they have never had.  (I am one of them...)

Comment: In such a case, what purpose would there be in reporting that your side mirror was bent by a tree while camping if you don't submit a claim, and simply bend it back yourself?  Or go buy a used replacement at a salvage yard?  Is there any relevance at all to an increased risk of careening into another vehicle on the highway?

Comment: @MichaelHall insurance doesn’t just cover collisions. It covers damage from theft, hailstorms etc. if you are a person who doesn’t “take care” then these risks might be higher. It doesn’t matter if they are higher - that’s for the insurer to assess and they need this information to do so.

Comment: Again, not necessarily.  I don't have coverage for hailstones or other random acts of nature.  And to my earlier point, I have renewed my policy dozens and dozens of times and have never been asked to report anything that wasn't claimed.  You are over generalizing in your answer.